# How to download and compile SwingX

Tags: java, swing, maven, swingx

This must be mostly a newbie Maven question.

Since SwingX migrated to Kenai, there are warnings all over the website that many links are broken.. so here is my best attempt.

1. I went to https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases
2. Clicked on "SwingX 1.6.4 All - Sources"  (really a non-intuitive, hit-or-miss choice for me, but perhaps it's a naming convention other people understand?)
3. This downloads swingx-all-1.6.4-sources.jar (why is it even a jar and not a zip?)

However, this source jar does not contain POM.XML.

So, I downloaded swingx-all-1.6.4.jar from the same link, renamed it to .zip, inflated. It does contain 
    META-INF\maven\org.swinglabs.swingx\swingx-all\POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>swingx-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>swingx-all</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>SwingX Complete</name>
  <description>A Maven project to aggregate all modules into a single artifact.</description>
  <properties>
    <project.generatedDependencies>${project.generatedSourcesDirectoy}/dependencies</project.generatedDependencies>
  </properties>
  <!-- make the dependent swingx modules optional, since we're aggregating -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>swingx-graphics</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>swingx-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>swingx-mavensupport</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jvnet-release</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>src-dependencies</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <classifier>sources</classifier>
                  <includeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</includeGroupIds>
                  <excludeArtifactIds>swingx-mavensupport</excludeArtifactIds>
                  <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>false</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.generatedDependencies}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>add-dependencies-source</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <sources>
                    <source>${project.generatedDependencies}</source>
                  </sources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>add-dependencies-resource</id>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>add-resource</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <resources>
                    <resource>
                      <directory>${project.generatedDependencies}</directory>
                      <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                      </excludes>
                    </resource>
                  </resources>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifestFile>${project.generatedAnnotations}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

When I change to the above directory where POM.XML is located and do mvn install, it certainly builds a lot of stuff.. but also says:

> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   F:\swingx\swingx-all-1.6.4\META-INF\m
>   Maven\org.swinglabs.swingx\swingx-all\src\main\resources

That's because the src directory is nonexistent. Which makes sense, because the .jar files in question is said to be binaries only, but I was hoping some Maven target would download sources or something... and if it's binary only, why does it need to be built? Confused.

At that point, I could probably either copy the src directory from the first zip file to the second, or copy the pom.xml from the second file to the first.. but I am having a feeling I am missing something, and there has to be a more straightforward way.

BTW, there is a third file at the same web page, swingx-mavensupport-1.6.4.jar

So I downloaded that, renamed it to .zip, inflated, found this file:
   META-INF\maven\org.swinglabs.swingx\swingx-mavensupport\POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>swingx-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>swingx-mavensupport</artifactId>
  <name>SwingX Maven Support</name>
</project>
```

Changed to its directory and ran mvn.install

However, that complained at the lack of a whole lot of files.

I must be getting it all wrong. What's the right way?

Comment: What, 1000 views and only two upvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following URL for SVN checkout: `https://svn.java.net/svn/swingx~svn`.
In trunk there is a correct `pom.xml` file (actualy many of them for different artifacts), so you can easily build the project yourself.

> swingx-all-1.6.4-sources.jar (why is it even a jar and not a zip?)

That's the default way sources are packaged and distributed in Maven.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try. However, since I am learning Maven, I am curious what's up with the downloaded files: are they busted, or was I doing something wrong?

Comment: These files are ok, you're just using them in a wrong way. Src-jar file is intended for documentation and analisys. For example, many IDEs can attach these jars to show you the library source if necessary. However, if your goal is to build a project from scratch, then the proper way is to checkout the sources as described above.

Comment: Then why the two pom.xml files I described? Anything useful I can do with them?

Comment: Look, SwingX project is a big one. It consists of several submodules: swingx-all, swingx-mavensupport and so on. For each submodule the is a separate pom.xml file. So what you have now is two different pom files for two different submodules. Using them you should be able to build these two submodules assuming you have all necessary sources, tests and resources. Jars you've downloaded are lacking many things necessary, so I doubt you can build anything useful without source code checkout.

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of Maven (or at least a major part of it) is automatic dependency management? I was thinking a POM file would automatically download everything it needs for a build?

Comment: That is true for well-formed projects assuming you have full source code & resources in hands. Missing stuff is not a dependency in terms of Maven, it's a part of SwingX project itself.

Comment: I did not quite understand that, but I guess I don't need to just yet. Now a newbie svn question: the link you gave me, does it download the release or a current build?

Comment: That's a root repository URL. In /trunk subfolder you'll find the latest source code available, probably unfinished and unstable. /tags contains source code snapshots for various releases, like Swingx-1-6-1, choose the one you need.

Comment: When I did 'svn checkout https:/ /svn.java.net/svn/swingx~svn', which version did that download?

Comment: Well, all of them. Latest version is in /trunk subfolder, older are in subfolders of /tags.

Comment: lol, that explains. I freaked out a bit about the size of swingx, was wondering if I even want to use a library that big :-)

Comment: OK, now trying to build different versions, starting from the latest version 1.6.5-1 backwards. Unfortunately, they all fail either compilation or unit tests :-(